# SSIS execute process task error while executing python script

Tags: python, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have ssis package which has execute process task to run the python script, when i execute the package and i am getting below error
it was running correctly in the SSDT, now i have migrated to VS 2019

Can you please advise

[image]

Comment: For future troubleshooting help, pictures are great but even better is the "Copy message"  button there. I was able to put IDTSApplication160 into my favorite search engine and quickly found discussions centered around that topic. And I chose that term as it seemed the least likely to give me seo optimized nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on the error message is that you have a mismatch between versions "it was working, now it's not".

I can't say specifically as you have provided no code to debug but given the error message, I found this interesting list of possibilities [Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Sql2019.IDTSApplication160'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731886/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-micros)